# How to install pip for python 3 in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python

I have followed some online solution , Please  help 
thank!

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl libreadline-dev
$ cd ~
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz
$ tar zxf Python-3.6.1.tgz
$ cd Python-3.6.1
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

but after install the Python3 i can not import  the telepot

```
peter@dvr:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.1
peter@dvr:~$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
peter@dvr:~$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 27 2019, 10:01:53)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import telepot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/peter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 346, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "/home/peter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telepot/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/peter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "/home/peter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "/home/peter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 3, in <module>
    import zlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
>>>
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to try and replace the Python version Ubuntu ships by default with a custom version. Many system components rely on the correct Python version and behaviour. You should instead install your custom version additionally, in a place and manner where it does not override e.g. the `python3` command. One simple way for Ubuntu LTS releases, instead of compiling yourself, is to use the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and install it as package from there.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Updating the package list using the following command:

```
sudo apt update
```

Step 2: Use the following command to install pip for Python 3:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Step 3: Once the installation is complete, verify the installation by checking the pip version:

```
pip3 --version
```